# How to get one column data in one field

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle

I have one table like

```
| Name | Address | (Column Name)
| rakesh  | ashok nagar |
| mahesh  | ashok nagar |
| rajesh  | ashok nagar |
| rakesh1 | ashok nagar |
| rakesh2 | ashok nagar |
| rakesh4 | mayur vihar  |
| rakesh5 | laxmi nahar  |
| rakesh6 | laxmi nahar  |
| rakesh7 | laxmi nahar1 |
| rakesh8 | laxmi nahar1 |
```

I need data something like this

```
+-------------+--------------+---------+
| count(name) | Address      | Name |
+-------------+--------------+---------+
|           5 | ashok nahgar | rakesh,mahesh,rajesh,rakesh1,rakesh2|
|           2 | laxmi nahar  | rakesh5,rakesh5|
|           2 | laxmi nahar1 | rakesh7,rakesh8 |
|           1 | mayur vihar  | rakesh4 |
+-------------+--------------+---------+
```

I am able to get same using temp table but My need is to get same using single line query.

Is It possible?

Comment: Please don't tag your questions with multiple database products unless you really need a solution which is platform independent.  It seems that's not what you want as you've selected a solution which only works for Oracle RDBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You have tagged oracle.  So we have Listagg function in oracle helps you to do this.

select count(name),address,listagg(name,',') within group(order by name)  "name"
from table
group by address;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this(as you tagged sql server),

```
SELECT Address,
       Stuff((SELECT ', ' + Cast(NAME AS VARCHAR(10)) [text()]
              FROM   #Your_Table
              WHERE  Address = t.Address
              FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE) .value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, ' ') List_Output,
       Count(Address) As [Count]
FROM   #Your_Table t
GROUP  BY Address
```